# Poincare Hopf: possible vector fields on the 2-sphere

Tags: differential-topology, vector-fields

According to the Poincare Hopf theorem, we know that the sum of the indices of the critical points of a flow over the 2-sphere is 2. I conclude that we can have one critical point having index 2, or two critical points having index 1 (e.g. the flow of west winds). But doesn't the flow of east winds over the sphere create two critical points of index -1? Or is it not possible to have such a vector field on the 2-sphere?

Comment: The local indices of the two critical points are the same when you go east or west. Look at a picture of what an index -1 critical point looks like.

Comment: @Pistachvis: In case it matters, if $p_{1}$, ..., $p_{n}$ are distinct points of the sphere and $i_{1}$, ..., $i_{n}$ are non-zero integers whose sum is $2$, there exists a smooth vector field on the sphere having a zero of index $i_{k}$ at $p_{k}$ (for each $k = 1$, ..., $n$) and no other zeros.

Answer (score 2):

The flow of east winds over the sphere that you wrote seems the following picture.

[image: A plane vector field with a zero of index 1]

The index of this flow must be $1$, not $-1$. Then the sum of indices of critical points is $2$.

The index $-1$ is the following picture.

[image: A plane vector field with a zero of index -1]

Comment: Thank you for answering. I can see the indices of those pictures are 1 and -1 respectively, but I am confused by imagining a flow like your first picture, but with the arrows going clockwise. The index is defined using the degree, and I was assuming going clockwise was reversing orientation. But it is not reversing the orientation?

Comment: If you reverse the arrow orientation, the index remains same. Going counter clockwise has also index 1. Please check the Gauss map.